# AngularJs Datatables Promise and Ignited Datatables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, datatables, angular-datatables

I'm having an issue populating a datatable in AngularJS,

```
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

My return from the API is below using Ignited Datatables,

```
        data: Array(145)
          [0 … 99]
            0: {id: "0", uid: "21912"}
            1: {id: "1", uid: "22000"}
            2: {id: "1.2345666664667e32", uid: "21967"}
            3: {id: "1.2345676773423e30", uid: "21970"}
            4: {id: "1.2345676777777e20", uid: "21969"}
            5: {id: "1001", uid: "22008"}
          [100 … 144]
            100: {id: "PS1548080820", uid: "22117"}
            101: {id: "PS1548081358", uid: "22118"}
            102: {id: "PS1548082263", uid: "22119"}
        draw: 0
        recordsFiltered: "145"
        recordsTotal: "145"
```

My Javascript is using a promise to get this information,

```
 $scope.dtColumns = DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
                    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('uid').withTitle('UID');

 $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function() 
 {
     return ApiService.GetTableDate($scope.searchParams, $scope.currentPage, $scope.pageSize).then(function (result) 
     {
         return result.data;
     });
 })
 .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
 .withOption('deferRender', true)
 .withDisplayLength(10)
 .withOption('initComplete', function() { });
```

and my HTML is below,

```
<table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns"
            class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>UID</th>
              <th>ID</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
</table>
```

Can anyone please help me on where I'm going wrong?

Much appreciated.

Comment: `ApiService.GetTableDate($scope.searchParams, $scope.currentPage, $scope.pageSize)` returns promise so you could do something like `function(){ return ApiService.GetTableDate($scope.searchParams, $scope.currentPage, $scope.pageSize); }`without all these defer stuff

Comment: thanks, that's easier.  Still have the same issue though.

Comment: Are you sure that `result.data` is your array and you don't have to call `result.data.data`?

Comment: no mate, it's definitely result.data

Comment: Have you tried removing `thead` tag and its children?

Comment: Yeah throws up a Javascript error...  TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

Comment: Is `$scope.dtColumns` assigned as here, or `$scope.dtColumns = [/*columns*/ ]`?

Comment: oh mate, you nailed it.  dtColumns wasn't an array, haha, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `[]` when assigning `$scope.dtColumns`, so it's not an array. Should be:

```js
$scope.dtColumns = [
  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('uid').withTitle('UID')
];
```